# set hdd flag to boot in linux now mac will not read the exfat filesystem

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning, exfat

I was trying to read an exfat file system in linux and removed the original flag of lba.then remembered I had to install exfat-utils.
The drive is still exfat but now will not mount to OSx mountain lion, when looking through diskutility I can see the hdd but the partition will not mount and I can not perform a verify or repair on the drive or partition. The hdd is external. Went back into my linux vm and managed to set the flag back to lba, unfortunately no mount in mac. Also I noticed in diskutility the info for the partition says linux but for the hdd info all is available.

Cannot back up the data via shares, linux or mac, there is over 600GB of data, art work,  music, docs etc and it is all important. Also have my fiancees data on there too (you guessed it, this was a manual backup disk)

Q's: how can I resolve without erasing data? How can I back up without erasing?  If I can back up all data I can then erase in mac and set the partition table appropriately.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for your continuing support, unfortunately I cannot  boot to a live Linux CD on my machine, I've shutdown and booted holding 'C' unfortunately no go.

Comment: Rod. S, You are right I am on VM and df shows the drive in the output however without being able to boot from the live Linux I cannot get the fdisk output you require.
Do either of you have a possible solution from within the VM or direct from the Mac host?

I will retry using the $ as neglected to do this, will provide an update tomorrow.

Thanks again.

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb1: 2000.4 GB, 2000398932992 bytes
245 heads, 52 sectors/track, 306674 cylinders, total 3907029166 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf4f4f4f4

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1p1   ?  4109694196  8219388391  2054847098   f4  SpeedStore

Comment: dosfsck 3.0.14 (23 Jan 2023)
dosfsck 3.0.14, 23 Jan 2023, FAT32, LFN
Logical sector size is zero.

Comment: When running the command sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sd'inserted correct value here'

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you've changed the [partition type code.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) Unfortunately, without detailed partitioning information from a tool like Linux's `fdisk` or `gdisk`, I can't be sure of this, and I can't provide information on how to fix the problem. I therefore recommend that you boot to Linux and type the following commands (as `root` or using `sudo`):

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb
gdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Edit your original question and post this output. This assumes that the disk in question is `/dev/sdb`; change that detail if necessary. Note also that many distributions don't install `gdisk` by default, so you may need to install it (usually in a package called `gdisk` or `gptfdisk`) first. Linux needs access to the whole-disk device, too. You mentioned running Linux in a virtual machine, so that may not be the case from your VM. If so, you may need to boot a Linux emergency disc on the "real" computer.

Answer (score 0):

I reinserted the disk into the MAC, booted to windows partition and performed a chkdsk /F (driveletter) which repaired the boot partition. Manged to get to the information after this. seems It is all fixed. Apple has this weird ability to screw the boot partition on exfat formatted disks when switching user accounts. They still haven't fixed this to this day (2018).